# Windows not recognizing g++ or gcc

Tags: c++

I downloaded the MinGW compiler for c and c++, I executed the installer and added the MinGW bin directory to the environment variables.

[image]

After that I tried to execute g++ --version on the cmd and I got the following error:

'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have closed and opened again the cmd and restated my computer but the error persists.

Comment: Did you try to reboot?

Comment: Restart your terminal/ shell and try again

Comment: I have closed and opened the cmd and restarted my pc.

Comment: Did you put `C:\MinGW\bin` in your System PATH?

Comment: Check that the executable is actually in the path you put into the PATH variable - there could be more than one location in that installation that has executable files.

Comment: I added it to the system variables, is it not the same thing?

Comment: No. PATH is one of many system variables, and each do different things.

Comment: [For more information about Environment Path](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) you can look there, but generally you can search YouTube for tutorials on how to do this. Main thing is that PATH is a list of directories where computer searches for applications when you ask for them. You can have it linked and pointed in every which way but if you don't say computer where it is it won't know where to look. General directory is just fine.

Answer (score -3):

You're adding the directory to the system variables, which are global and *cannot* be changed by any user. They are set by Windows itself, and any other programmes or drivers installed. Instead, you should be adding `C:\MinGW\bin` to the user variables right above the system variables in the Environment Variables. Specifically, the value should be added to the `Path` variable (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).